# Using codenameone command causes NullPointerException on Android but works in simulator

Tags: android, codenameone

I am building a mobile app using codenameone, and I have various forms which I add one or two commands to a Form with code like this:

```
void goConfigAlerts(final Form previousForm) {
    final Form caf = new Form("configure alerts");

    caf.setBackCommand(new Command("home"){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            previousForm.showBack();
        }
    });

    caf.addCommand(new Command("add") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            AlertFilter af = new AlertFilter(settings);
            af.goAlertFilter(caf, "add");
        }
    });
    caf.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    showAlertFilters(caf);
    caf.show();
}
```

These commands work fine when I run in the Codenameone simulator, but when I make an Android build and test it out on a Nexus 5, the app crashes as soon as I bring up the menu and select one of these commands.  The back commands work fine though, the crash only happens on the normal commands, in this case, the one I named "add".  I hooked the phone up to the monitor, and the app crashes due to the following exception:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.ioscode.gameaid.mypackage, PID: 31466
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.getVisibleItems()' on a null object reference
>   at android.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:613)
>   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1082)
>   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.getNonActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1114)
>   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper$MenuAdapter.getCount(MenuPopupHelper.java:373)
>   at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:828)
>   at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:6203)
>   at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
>   at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
>   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper$MenuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(MenuPopupHelper.java:427)
>   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.updateMenuView(MenuPopupHelper.java:288)
>   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:257)
>   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:976)
>   at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:999)
>   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:601)
>   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:939)
>   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:271)
>   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
>   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Is there some other way to implement the command to avoid this exception?

Comment: Are you running on Marshmallow? Seems to be related to https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1605

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195783&q=label%3AReportedBy-Developer&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: Yeah, seems to be the same thing.  I was able to test on a different device running Android 5 and it works fine on that older Android release.

Comment: Can you comment on the Android issues link above and answer their questions?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Toolbar class instead

```
            final Form caf = new Form("configure alerts");
            Toolbar bar = new Toolbar();                
            caf.setToolBar(bar);
            caf.addCommandToSideMenu(...);
```